# How to generate unique primary key values with union all clause on same table with sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, union-all

I have this query which return Pk of my tables like this:

```
select Id from employee

1
2
3
4
etc...
```

Now if i add 1 union all clause then i want output like this in which there should be no repetation of primary key values:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

But when i add 1 more union all clause i want to display output like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

I have think of this but got repetation:

```
select Id from employee
union all
select Id + 1 from employee
```

Then i thought of max function but still didnt work out:

```
select Id from employee
union all
select (max(Id) + 1) from employee
```

This is 1 sample fiddle i have created:[Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f065d/4)

Is this possible to do this with just sql query??

Comment: Is this a theoretical question, or is there some purpose?  In the sqlfiddle, the table is defined having an AUTO_INCREMENT key, so it will insert the next key automatically whenever a new row is added.  It's not worth pre-allocated rows as there will be empty rows that take up disk space.

Comment: @benson:This task is not for the insert purpose and yeah there is specific purpose behind this and i want to get this output with sql query

Comment: In the question, you have used the tag SQL-SERVER which implies the SQL you are using MS-SQL, however the fiddle you shared uses MySQL.. there is a difference between the two, so please clarify..

Comment: @SujeetSinha:Actually i have tried using sql server but i was getting some error while creating scheme so i end up using mysql.but originally i am using sql server

Comment: If you still want solution for MS-SQL, check my post below.. that should get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMER()` like following. The answer is valid for MS-SQL, per my knowledge.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.ID) AS EmployeeID
FROM 
(
SELECT ID FROM employee
UNION ALL
SELECT ID FROM employee
) A
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, updated my post as per your comment. didnt want to comment for other SQL environments, which I aint aware of!

Comment: suppose if i want to give column name as EmployeeId in my output then how can i give because with your query i am not getting any column name in my output

Comment: can you please explain me a little how this row number worked??

Comment: Its a very simple mechanism of assigning a sequential number for each row returned. For `ROW_NUMBER()`, it is mandatory to define the order in which the records should be sorted using the `OVER` clause. This helps assign the correct sequence number to the record. You can check the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114932/discussion-between-sujeet-sinha-and-learning).